# Change VARCHAR number

Tags: mysql

I cannot find the information on how to change VARCHAR number of a column of a mysql table.

For instance I have a table "Table1" that contains 2 columns : "ID" and "Response".

"Response" is using VARCHAR 150 and I want to change it to VARCHAR 2000.

What would be the full sql command?

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `Response`...?
```

Thank you for your help.
Roman

Comment: To change the table structure, use `ALTER TABLE` query instead of `UPDATE`, which is for update the *contents* in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `alter` table command to change the definition of a column, but not `update`.

```
alter table `table1` modify response varchar(2000)
```

And make sure that other related attributes, like `not null default 'some xyz'`, etc, are also included

Comment: Thanks @Ravinder. Well I to alter the entire column "response" of table 1, so all the rows will be affected. Some have "Response" null, some have "Response" with values inside. I am not sure what you mean with "make sure that other related attributes, like `not null default 'some xyz', etc, are also included "?

Comment: Changing the column length will not affect the data unless the target length is less than that of a max length string in the column. NULL have no side effect.

Comment: Well, on the *make sure....* part, before applying `alter`, execute `show create table table1` and you will see other attributes on the column `response`. Use the same attributes with alter command as well. Example: `alter table table1 modify response varchar(2000) not null default ''`.

Comment: It worked thanks @Ravinder. Last questions. If I do alter table `table1` modify response varchar(2000) default'' only. Meaning I do not specify "not null" what is the impact?

Comment: `NOT NULL` is to restrict new inserts on not including the field and in updates not setting the value to NULL. Your current change will not affect anything, unless you have a trigger on the table and you do some check on this field for NULL. Setting *empty* is *not null*. I hope, you know this.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the table definition using an `UPDATE`. `UPDATE`s are for data in the table. You need to use the [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) command to change the table definition.

The statement to use would be

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` MODIFY COLUMN response VARCHAR(2000)
```

Please note that the part after `MODIFY COLUMN` takes a full column specification, so if any special attributes were set for the column (like `NOT NULL` or a default value), you must specify them again here, as the `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN ...` command will not just change the specified attribute (for example the type), but replace the old column definition with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `Table1`
  MODIFY COLUMN `Response` VARCHAR(100)
```

But why don't you use Text?